# For a single static variable in c++, is there a better option than a class?

Tags: c++

When I have a program that needs a random number generator, I use this class so that the entire program can run on the same rng.

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Rizzian {
private:
    static mt19937 mt;
public:
    void initialize() {
        mt.seed(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    }
    unsigned int r() {
        return mt();
    }
};
```

This requires that the following line occurs elsewhere in the code (outside of any function or class definition):

```
mt19937 Rizzian::mt = mt19937();
```

When the rng is initialized and I have the variable `Rizzian rng`, I get random numbers with `rng.r()`.

But having an extra line outside of Rizzian's definition makes me feel as though there's some better way I could be doing this, and in general an entire class for one static variable feels like overkill. So this is just a hunch for me. Something stinks here.

This isn't a specific question about rngs or mersenne twisters or anything. Is there a better way to make a static variable the entire program can access?

Comment: `mt` should not be a static member, but a `Rizzian` instance, possibly global, is created somewhere else. Look up singleton pattern.

Comment: The `initialize` function should just be replaced with better initialization of the object, but really, this could just be a function if you want to keep it working this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for a class just for this function.  Functions can also contain static members.  The lines with the static keyword are only executed once.

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned int rnd()
{
  static bool first_call = true;
  static mt19937 mt = mt19937();

  if (first_call)
  {
    mt.seed(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    first_call = false;
  }

  return mt();
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int r = rnd();
  std::cout << r << std::endl;

  for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
  {
    r = rnd();
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
  }
}
```